# odoo 16: style used in tree view showing error

Tags: odoo

environment = OS: Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, Odoo 16 + Pycharm CE
when using style in tree view and trying upgrading module/app it is showing below error. we have 4 fields/columns in this tree view, the name column occupying almost 80% of space and rest used by another 3, i was searching to control column's width and found below solution at [Link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/column-width-on-tree-view-in-odoo15-205834)

i used as: `<field name="name" style="width: 50px !important;"/>`

please help how i can add style to resize columns, and columns headers.

below is error text generated by odoo on upgrading module.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1587, in _serve_db
        return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 134, in retrying
        result = func()
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1614, in _serve_ir_http
        response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1811, in dispatch
        result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
        response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
        result = endpoint(**request.params)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 700, in route_wrapper
        result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
        action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
        return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 461, in call_kw
        result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
        result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
      File "<decorator-gen-80>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 76, in check_and_log
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 678, in button_immediate_upgrade
        return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 615, in _button_immediate_function
        registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
      File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in new
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked
        return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 90, in new
        odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 483, in load_modules
        processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 371, in load_marked_modules
        loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 230, in load_module_graph
        load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 71, in load_data
        tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in convert_file
        convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 829, in convert_xml_import
        obj.parse(doc.getroot())
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 749, in parse
        self._tag_root(de)
      File "/home/odoo16/odoo-server/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 709, in _tag_root
        raise ParseError(msg) from None  # Restart with "--log-handler odoo.tools.convert:DEBUG" for complete traceback
    odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /home/odoo16/odoo-server/custom_addons/om_hospital/views/units_config.xml:38
    Invalid view unitsconfig.tree (om_hospital.config_unit_types_tree_view) definition in om_hospital/views/units_config.xml
    
    View error context:
    '-no context-'
    
    
    The above server error caused the following client error:
    RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
        RPCError@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10193:9 (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:11)

makeErrorFromResponse@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10216:19 (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:34)
        jsonrpc/promise</<@http://localhost:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10269:48 (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:87)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from this line of code.
I think a tag must be closed incorrectly or you have a typo somewhere in your view

Comment: thanks @AlexisYovanofski ,  before adding this style it was working perfectly, when added it, now it is showing error while upgrading module. i removed it, upgrade and run ... everthing is fine but not when add it again. one thing to mention, i have used `<field name="reg_date" class="text-center"/>` and it is working fine, but when using style it is throwing error.

Comment: So, you can try to use the bootstrap width class : 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/
Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the link, i used class="w-25 p-1" , saved file, re-run odoo server, upgraded module successfully, run app, but nothing happened.  i don't think so but (may be) is there any odoo module needs to install? i have activated website. regrads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restart Odoo with `--log-handler odoo.tools.convert:DEBUG` as it is mentioned in the error log above, you should see the following error:

```
Invalid attribute style for element field
```

According to the [rng](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/rng/common.rng#L206) validation file, `style` is not a valid field attribute.

Instead, you can add a CSS file and use the `class` attribute.

***Example:***

1. Add the CSS file in the assets entry in the manifest file:

   ```
   'assets': {
       'web.assets_backend': [
           '{MODULE_NAME}/static/src/css/tree.css',
       ],
   },
   ```
2. Define a class to limit the field width:

   ```
   .w50 {
       max-width: 50px !important;
   }
   ```
3. Set the class attribute on the field:

   ```
    <field class="w50" .../>
   ```

Comment: thanks @Kenly for detailed help, will check this and confirm, sorry for delay in response.  regards